# when adding a class, styles are applied without smooth transition

Tags: css

I want an element to get applied some styles in a smooth way after 2 seconds. I tried setTimeout, to add the class after two seconds, but despite having declared `transition: all 1s` to absolutely everything, when the class (containing new styles )is added, I can't see any "transition", the new styles are just applied without smoothness.

How can I fix it?

```js
var s2 = document.querySelector("#section2");
setTimeout(() => {
  s2.classList.add("up");
}, 2000);
```

```css
html * {
  transition: 1s all;
}

body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

#section1 {
  background: steelblue;
}

#section2 {
  background: indigo;
  position: absolute;
}

section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.up {
  top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<section id="section1"></section>
<section id="section2"></section>
```

What I want to achieve is that the div that is below the first one start moving up until it reaches the top of the window, like a "slide-up" effect. Why are "transition" property being ignored after adding the class containing this new styles?

Comment: Have you looked at CSS Transitions? https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp

Comment: missing initial value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to apply an initial value for the `top` rule to allow the transition to take effect.

```js
var s2 = document.querySelector("#section2");
setTimeout(() => {
  s2.classList.add("up");
}, 2000);
```

```css
html * {
  transition: 1s all;
}

body {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative; /** ensure section#section2 is positioned relative to the body **/
}

#section1 {
  background: steelblue;
}

#section2 {
  background: indigo;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100vh; /** initial value **/
}

section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

/** #section2.up is more specific **/
#section2.up {
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<section id="section1"></section>
<section id="section2"></section>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also animate with an external library like jQuery:

```js
$("#section2").animate({
  top: 0,
  duration: 2000
});
```

```css
html * {
  transition: 1s all;
}

body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

#section1 {
  background: steelblue;
}

#section2 {
  background: indigo;
  position: absolute;
}

section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<section id="section1"></section>
<section id="section2"></section>
```